# Can I expand my storage options with a PCI-E card in a PCI slot?

Tags: sata, nas, pci-express, pci, file-server

I have an [Intel D945GCLF2](http://ark.intel.com/products/42491/Intel-Desktop-Board-D945GCLF2) running headless Ubuntu which I use as a fileserver. I currently have a 4 port PCI SATA card plugged into it which has 4 disks attached. They're running software RAID 5 which is plenty fast enough to stream music etc.

Unforunately I've run out of space on those drives and am looking to upgrade. I've been hunting around for an 8-port PCI Sata card but they're few and far between unless you want to pay >£500!

My question is whether the following would work:

1. Plug [a PCI to PCI-E converter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Startech-com-PCI-Express-Adapter-Card/dp/B0037ECAM2/ref=lh_ni_t) into the motherboard.
2. Plug [an 8 port PCI-Ex4 card](http://www.scan.co.uk/products/supermicro-aoc-saslp-mv8-8-port-sas-sata-300mb-s-pci-e-controller-card) into the adapter.
3. Plug my existing 4 drives plus some additional drives into a couple of [SFF-8087 to SATA cables](http://compare.ebay.co.uk/like/251009403680?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar&adtype=pla)

My main worry is that the converter says it'll do pci to pci-e x1 but the card says it'll do x4 and makes no mention of x1?

Will this all work? ..and if not, is there an alternative?

Comment: You can find 3Ware 9500S-12 cards for under $100 new and under $50 used. They'll work in a PCI slot. I believe they are not officially supported on 64-bit Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Comment: Any converter board is going to come with a performance cost.  Furthermore any converter board connected to a PCI slot is going to be limited to the speed of the PCI Slot.  PCI-Ex4 is supports PCI-E X 1 but its a horrible idea.  Of course your current setup is sort of bad also, so you clearly don't care about performance, your getting a fraction of the speed that a SATA HDD should provide IF THAT.

Comment: What I care about is a large storage volume, performance high enough to stream content, some degree of redundancy (RAID5 gives me the capability to suffer a single drive failure before I have issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. A Lycom ST-125 (SiL3124 chipset based PCI controller card) for ~£30.
2. A Lycom ST-126RM (SiL3726 chipset 1-5 port expander) for ~£30.

The first card has 4 ports on it and the expanders have 5. So if I buy another 3 expanders I can support up to 20 disks with this arrangement.

My existing 4x1TB software RAID 5 array is managing ~20MB/s read / write on the new card. Next up is trying it when it's on the port extender to see how much of a performance hit we get there. It definitely works though and fast enough for my needs.

If anyone else is looking for a relatively low power, low cost, reliable storage array, this configuration works rather well!